# Move two images independentaly android

Tags: android, android-emulator, touch, android-imageview, android-sdcard

I have two imageview in which i am adding image by using setImageBitmap and also apply setOnTouchListener to them. But here problem is that for the first time when add first img, its move by touch but when i add second img, the second img move but after that i can't move first img by touch. Sorry for english and thanks in advanced. This is my code :-

```
    working_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_location+"cropped_image.jpg");  

    outBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(
    working_bitmap.getWidth(),
    working_bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
    Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(outBitmap);
    canvas1.drawBitmap(working_bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    if(downloaded_shirt_image != null)
    {
        int width = downloaded_shirt_image.getWidth();
    int height = downloaded_shirt_image.getHeight();
    int halfWidth = width/3;
    int halfHeight = height/3;
    //Half Scaled
    Bitmap bmHalf = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(downloaded_shirt_image,
            halfWidth, halfHeight, false);
    proimg =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pro_img);
    proimg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    proimg.setImageBitmap(bmHalf);
    proimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    proimg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    int rotation = 25;
    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
        mode = DRAG;
        proimg.invalidate();
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (mode == DRAG) {
    // ...
                                                                                           matrix.set(savedMatrix);                                                   matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
    event.getY() - start.y);
     }
     else if (mode == ZOOM) {
     float newDist = spacing(event);
     Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
     if (newDist > 10f) {
     matrix.set(savedMatrix);
     float scale = newDist / oldDist;
     matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
     }
     }
     proimg.invalidate();
     break;
     }
     view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
     return true; // indicate event was handled
     }
     });
     canvas1.drawBitmap(downloaded_shirt_image, 50, 192, null);
     }

     if(downloaded_pant_image != null)
     {
      int width = downloaded_pant_image.getWidth();
      int height = downloaded_pant_image.getHeight();
      int halfWidth = width/3;
      int halfHeight = height/3;
      //Half Scaled
      Bitmap bmHalf = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(downloaded_pant_image,
                      halfWidth, halfHeight, false);
      pantimg =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pro_img_down);
      pantimg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      pantimg.setImageBitmap(bmHalf);
      pantimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      pantimg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
      {
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
       int rotation = 25;
       // Dump touch event to log
       dumpEvent(event);
      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      savedMatrix.set(matrix);
      start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
      Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
      mode = DRAG;
      pantimg.invalidate();
      break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      if (mode == DRAG) {
      // ...

     matrix.set(savedMatrix);                                              matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
     event.getY() - start.y);
     }
    else if (mode == ZOOM) {
    float newDist = spacing(event);
    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
    if (newDist > 10f) {
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
    }
    }
    pantimg.invalidate();
    break;
    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; // indicate event was handled
    }
   }                            
   );
   canvas1.drawBitmap(downloaded_pant_image, 110, 565, null);
   }
```

Comment: hello if u get solution how to move two image on hole screen please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for that and use Imageview instead of Textview.

```
windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();


tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
tv2.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: what it is type of "layoutParams1"?

Comment: Declare RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1; and RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2; in your activity.

Comment: yes two images move independently but problem is that we cannot move image on whole screen rather it move only on specific area defined in  tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2); is any way to move on whole screen

Comment: Sorry for that but i have no more idea about this.

Comment: what is windowwidth and windowheight? Its a system define or your define. currently i am taking my image width and height.